# net.mail and web.mail vs gmail

Tags: c#, email

I am wondering, if I can use `System.Net.Mail` with 465 port and `System.Web.Mail` with 587 port. For example for gmail, I cannot switch ports in this example as it will throw transport protocol exception...

```
using web = System.Web.Mail;
using net = System.Net.Mail;

private void SendMail()
{
    web.MailMessage webMail = new web.MailMessage();
    webMail.To = "MAILTO@gmail.com";
    webMail.From = "MAILFROM@gmail.com";

    webMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusing", "2");
    webMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpusessl", "true");            
    webMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpauthenticate", "1");
    webMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendusername", "LOGIN");
    webMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/sendpassword", "PASSWORD");
    webMail.Fields.Add("http://schemas.microsoft.com/cdo/configuration/smtpserverport", 465);
    web.SmtpMail.SmtpServer = "smtp.gmail.com";
    web.SmtpMail.Send(webMail);

    net.SmtpClient smtp = new net.SmtpClient();
    smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
    smtp.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("LOGIN", "PASSWORD");
    smtp.Port = 587;
    smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
    smtp.EnableSsl = true;

    var netMail = new net.MailMessage(new net.MailAddress("MAILFROM@gmail.com", "", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8),
                                      new net.MailAddress("MAILTO@gmail.com", "", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8));

    smtp.Send(netMail); 
}
```

I am asking because even the simplest second `Net.Mail` cannot be sent under Russian Win 7 64x in .Net 2.0 build - it throws exception about invalid character in the header... And We.Mail works as expected. But I dont want to use it...

Comment: I think you mean SMTP, not pop. Pop is for retrieving mails, SMTP sending.

Comment: You're right to avoid System.Web.Mail - it's obsolete, and based on an ancient COM component which was flaky at best. Have you tried setting the `HeadersEncoding` property on the `MailMessage`? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.headersencoding.aspx http://www.systemnetmail.com/faq/4.9.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately there is no HeadersEncoding property in .Net 2.0 and setting Subject and Body encoding wont help.